# How to recognize which methods are getters and setters?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to get all class methods. I want to prepare an algorithm that will recognize which methods are getters and setters.

So, as you see I am printing each **getter** in the format: `{name} will return {Return Type}`. I am trying to print all of the **setters** in the format: `{name} will set field of {Parameter Type}`, but I don't know how to get the `Parameter Type`.

```
public string CollectGettersAndSetters(string className)
{
    Type classType = Type.GetType(className);

    MethodInfo[] getters = classType
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("get"))
        .ToArray();

    MethodInfo[] setters = classType
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("set"))
        .ToArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (MethodInfo getter in getters)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{getter.Name} will return {getter.ReturnType}");
    }

    foreach (MethodInfo setter in setters)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{setter.Name} will set field of {?}");
    }

    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

An example of class for which I will use the method:

```
public class Hacker
{
    public string username = "securityGod82";
    private string password = "mySuperSecretPassw0rd";

    public string Password
    {
        get => this.password;
        set => this.password = value;
    }

    private int Id { get; set; }

    public double BankAccountBalance { get; private set; }

    public void DownloadAllBankAccountsInTheWorld()
    {
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
get_Password will return System.String
get_Id will return System.Int32
get_BankAccountBalance will return System.Double
set_Password will set field of System.String
set_Id will set field of System.Int32
set_BankAccountBalance will set field of System.Double
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first parameter, and then use `ParameterType`:

```
var parameter = setter.GetParameters()[0];
sb.AppendLine($"{setter.Name} will set field of {parameter.ParameterType}");
```

I suggest you do some more checking, just to make sure it is actually a setter:

```
var parameters = setter.GetParameters();
if (parameters.Length != 1) { continue; }
sb.AppendLine($"{setter.Name} will set field of {parameters[0].ParameterType}");
```

EDIT:

Actually, you can get the setters by first getting the properties, then call the [`GetSetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetSetMethod) method, which is a much safer approach than iterating through all the methods.

```
MethodInfo[] setters = classType
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(x => x.GetSetMethod(true))
        .Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
```

The same thing goes for getters - with `GetGetMethod`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your help! I know that setters and getters are like methods, but which are parameters of setters?

Comment: @KaloyanK. When you do something like `someObj.SomeProperty = someValue`. You are calling the setter and passing the parameter of `someValue`.

Comment: @KaloyanK. See the edit. You should be using `GetGetMethod` and `GetSetMethod` to get the getters and setters, not iterating through all the methods because you might get false positives.

Comment: @Sweeper. You should also check for private setters. **MethodInfo[] setters = classType.GetProperties ().Select (x => x.GetSetMethod ()).Where (x => x != null).ToArray ();**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of parameters with:

```
var parameters = setter.GetParameters();
```

Since it's a setter, it will have only one parameter, so you can do

```
var setterType = setter.GetParameters().First().ParameterType;
```

to access its `Type`.